# Search bar added to a contacts list

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

So I am following a tutorial and I am wanting to add a search bar at the top of a contacts list page however I can't seem to get the search bar to even show up in my app. I was able to get the search bar working in my code initially by itself, but it wont show up like it used too. I'm sure it will have something to do with the structure but any advice would be great, I just can't seem to get it right.

Answer (score 0):

We dont need the `_SearchBar` class. We have to merge the `AppBar` of `_SearchBar` and `ContactsPage`. We have to make the `ContactsPage` as `Stateful` which will state variables as

```
 Icon actionIcon
 Widget appBarTitle
```

**Updated with code:**

```
  import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

  class ContactsPage extends StatefulWidget {
    Widget appBarTitle = new Text("Contacts");
    Icon actionIcon = new Icon(Icons.search);

    @override
    State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
      return new _ContactPage();
    }
  }

  class _ContactPage extends State<ContactsPage> {
    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return new MaterialApp(
        home: new Scaffold(
            appBar: new AppBar(
              title: widget.appBarTitle,
              actions: <Widget>[
                new IconButton(
                  icon: widget.actionIcon,
                  onPressed: () {
                    setState(() {
                      if (widget.actionIcon.icon == Icons.search) {
                        widget.actionIcon = new Icon(Icons.close);
                        widget.appBarTitle = new TextField(
                          style: new TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.white,
                          ),
                          decoration: new InputDecoration(
                              prefixIcon:
                                  new Icon(Icons.search, color: Colors.white),
                              hintText: "Search...",
                              hintStyle: new TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
                          onChanged: (value) {
                            print(value);
                            //filter your contact list based on value
                          },
                        );
                      } else {
                        widget.actionIcon =
                            new Icon(Icons.search); //reset to initial state
                        widget.appBarTitle = new Text("Contacts");
                      }
                    });
                  },
                ),
              ],
            ),
            body: new Text("contact list")),
            // replace the body with your contacts list view
      );
    }
  }

  void main() {
    runApp(new ContactsPage());
  }
```

Comment: So how would I merge into contacts page? I will updated original code post